# Awk not working in bash script

Tags: awk

I am facing a perplexing (at least for me) problem. I'm trying to read some csv files and then extract some values to make some checking and calculus. I'm using awk to access files and extract required fields.

The strange point is that the awk sentence properly runs on a bash prompt but it does not work when run in the script. As an example I get from bash prompt:

```
paco@NIMBUS:~/work$ awk -F\; '$1 == "21-08-2012" && $2 == "'17'" { print $3 }' niveles-rams.csv
2
```

but

```
nrams1=`awk -F\; '$1 == "'$fecha'" && $2 == "'$area'" { print $3 }' niveles-rams.csv`
echo $nrams1
```

does not return any value. CSV files come from an Excel in windows so maybe there could be a problem with encoding, I guess?

You can find the script validacio.bash and csv files in the following URL

- [niveles-rams.csv](http://ubuntuone.com/5b0vTvZ82B5a9GfqaplxbT)
- [pobles.csv](http://ubuntuone.com/3B94FmzzgKS7DdM4l4acBr)
- [umbrales.csv](http://ubuntuone.com/02FVmuWK2jc8bqNwCxc1XE)
- [validacio.bash](http://ubuntuone.com/3RuSyLSQGa4svsqEbzaaow)

Thanks for your help and patience

Comment: I suggest you re-read the answers to your last question.

Comment: I'll do, thanks. The point is that same awk sentence is working in the script for a different input file but I tried to save all files as UTF8 to avoid problems coming from the fact that they were produced with Excel.

Comment: See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for how to pass the value of shell variables to an awk script and the answer posted here by @JacekDominiak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case will be:

```
nrams1=`awk -F";" -v fecha=$fecha -v area=$area '$1 == fecha && $2 == area { print $3 }' niveles-rams.csv`
```

as **Kailash K Pawar** menitioned the right method

Comment: always quote your shell variables unless you have a very specific reason not to. fecha="$fecha" and area="$area".

Comment: What would be the reason for that? I can imagine that if you do connect them ... you can use curly brackets as _${fecha}_ ... but quote? What is the difference for interpreter?

Comment: Huge difference. Within quotes you get the string that the variable contained. Without quotes you get the result of applying word splitting, filename expansion, etc,. etc. to the string the variable contained. As a trivial example, try this in writeable directory: > tmp1; > tmp2; var="tmp*"; echo "$var"; echo $var

Comment: ...The output of the first echo will be "tmp*" and the output of the second echo will be "tmp1 tmp2". There are many other potentially unexpected results of not quoting your variable.

Comment: See also the comment I just posted at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13088359/1745001 for a different problem with an unquoted variable.

Comment: Amazingly yet another manifestation of the same problem just occurred. See my comment at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13088026/1745001. I won't post any more examples, just trust me - quote your shell variables.

Answer (score 0):

In your file (niveles-rams.csv) in date field you using / (slash) symbol but in bash script - (minus) symbol. Maybe that is the reason.

Comment: Sorry, uploaded older version. That's not the problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone answering and commenting the question. The problem in my script was an awk issue but not the one I asked. My mistake was that I was not properly reading "area" variable in:

```
i=1
while [ $i -lt 32 ]     
   do
     let i=$i+1
     area=`awk 'BEGIN { FS=";" ; FNR="1" } FNR == "'$i'" {print $1}' pobles.csv`
```

File *pobles.csv* has not a header and the script was not properly reading first record. Then errors were cascading and so final result was wrong. Now, adding a header and starting to read from i=2 (second record) it works.

For sure, there has to be a smarter solution but I'm a novice to awk and can't get the point. Hope I will learn more awk and do the trick.

All your answers have been very useful for me and made me learn something about awk.

Thanks